# React on Rails argument error when prerender is true

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-on-rails

Setting `prerender: true` in `index.html.erb`

```
<%= react_component('App', props: @props, prerender: true) %>
```

Triggers the following error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
```

Here's the `initializers/react_on_rails.rb`, if helpful:

```
ReactOnRails.configure do |config|
  config.build_test_command = "RAILS_ENV=test bin/webpack"
  config.same_bundle_for_client_and_server = true
end
```

The Full Trace from the Rails error view:

```
react_on_rails (12.2.0) lib/react_on_rails/prerender_error.rb:12:in `initialize'
react_on_rails (12.2.0) lib/react_on_rails/helper.rb:486:in `exception'
react_on_rails (12.2.0) lib/react_on_rails/helper.rb:486:in `raise'
react_on_rails (12.2.0) lib/react_on_rails/helper.rb:486:in `rescue in server_rendered_react_component'
react_on_rails (12.2.0) lib/react_on_rails/helper.rb:482:in `server_rendered_react_component'
react_on_rails (12.2.0) lib/react_on_rails/helper.rb:424:in `internal_react_component'
react_on_rails (12.2.0) lib/react_on_rails/helper.rb:57:in `react_component'
app/views/app/index.html.erb:1
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/base.rb:247:in `public_send'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/base.rb:247:in `_run'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:154:in `block in render'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:345:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:152:in `render'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `block in render_template'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:71:in `block in render_with_layout'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:70:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `render_template'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:11:in `render'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:61:in `render_template_to_object'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:29:in `render_to_object'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:117:in `block in _render_template'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/base.rb:273:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:116:in `_render_template'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:218:in `_render_template'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/Users/tristan/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block in render'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:86:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (6.1.4.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:45:in `render'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:35:in `default_render'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (6.1.4.1) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (6.1.4.1) lib/action_text/engine.rb:59:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.1.4.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
actionview (6.1.4.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (1.9.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
activerecord (6.1.4.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
airbrake (11.0.3) lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:34:in `call!'
airbrake (11.0.3) lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:23:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.1.4.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.4.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:98:in `call'
rack-mini-profiler (2.3.3) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:393:in `call'
rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'
webpacker (5.4.3) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.7.0) lib/rack/proxy.rb:63:in `call'
railties (6.1.4.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
rack-reverse-proxy (0.11.0) lib/rack_reverse_proxy/roundtrip.rb:19:in `call'
rack-reverse-proxy (0.11.0) lib/rack_reverse_proxy/middleware.rb:25:in `call'
puma (5.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
puma (5.4.0) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.4.0) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
puma (5.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:440:in `process_client'
puma (5.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The local server logs error:

```
  Rendered app/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 20125.9ms | Allocations: 15468)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 20126.6ms | Allocations: 15537)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20133ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms | Allocations: 17982)


  AdminUser Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
    1: <%= react_component('App', props: @props, prerender: true) %>

app/views/app/index.html.erb:1
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace if possible. What you have posted here specifically will not raise that error (mostly because you passed 2 arguments or 1 positional argument and 2 keyword arguments depending on the method signature)

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky. I've just added the Rails Error view Full Trace & local server error logs. Please let me know if there's anything else I can add which will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
config.same_bundle_for_client_and_server = true
```

Don’t use that.

You need a different config for SSR.

Use the setup in

https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails_tutorial_with_ssr_and_hmr_fast_refresh

as an example.